# How to implement a dynamic js script in Yii List View?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hello and thanks for reading my question. I have a typical list view:

```
 <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
        'emptyText'=>'No Jobs',             
)); ?>
```

In my _view file I have a div and a button that slideToggles the div. If I just put the Javascript at the top of the page, it does not work because the results are dynamic and the name of the div changes with the id returned, eg:

```
id="detailsDiv-<?php echo $data->id_employer_contract;?>"
```

The problem is in my Javascript, which is as follows:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('details', "$('#details-$data-id_employer_contract').click(function(){
$('#detailsDiv-$data->id_employer_contract').slideToggle();
return false;});");?>
```

How can I make this Javascript code dynamic? Meaning, how can I loop through the id? I tried adding the code to the listview property `ajaxUpdate` but it's still not working. Can someone tell me how I can loop a Javascript in a list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `id` to your toggle buttons as data attribute:

```
<button class="toggleDetails" data-id="<?php echo $data->id_employer_contract ?>">
```

Then you can access these data attributes like this js:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('toggleDetails', "
    $('.toggleDetails').click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#detailsDiv-' + id).slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
", CClientScript::POS_READY) ?>
```

**NOTE:** You should not put this javascript into `_view.php` but into the main file where you render the List View. You only need this one single snippet to deal with all your buttons.

Comment: hey i tried your solution but the generated code after a view the source looks like this ;    $('#details-7').click(function(e){
        $('.detailsDiv').slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
This makes the click on the final button close all the divs i need each button the close the corresponding div

Comment: You must have forgotten something. That's completely different from what i wrote above. Look carefully: I use `$('.toggleDetails').click(..)`. Also make sure, that you put that Js into the view file, where your List View is created.

Comment: Oh, and sorry, i've updated my initial answer again. So maybe you should try again with the above :)

Comment: thanks a lot , you saved me a lot of time this morning your answer is correct